# Как в JS сделать такой массив или объект?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Объект или массив, когда нужно сделать такую вещь:

```
var obj = (0 => (name => 'Name', 'value' => '2'), 1 => (name => 'Name2', 'value' => '3'));
```

Т.е. этот объект будет формроваться в цикле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что значит сделать - я не понял. Но если представить, что вы пытались показать аналог ассоциативного многомерного массива на php, то его аналог в JS будет такой:

```
var obj = {
    0: {name : 'Name', value : 2},
    1: {name : 'Name2', value : 3}
};
```

Comment: Либо, если предположить, что индексы последовательные, от нуля, то:

    var obj = [
        { "name": "Name", "value": 2},
        { "name": "Name2", "value": 3},
    ];

Comment: @Sergiks, оператор присваивания "=>" больше говорит об ассоциативном массиве на всех уровнях вложенности, но, конечно же, не суть важно... )) 

А я решил чуть дополнить свой ответ, т.к. писал позно и "проглотил" часть мысли. Мне не понятно, из чего формировать объект, откуда берутся данные. Вот если @Oleg Ponomarchuk откроет эту тайну, тогда уже можно будет думать о том, как будет выглядеть цикл для формирования объекта.